# iOS : is there a leak?

Tags: ios, nsthread

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Todo.h"
@interface TodoCostApplyViewController : UIViewController

{
    NSThread* headViewThread;
    NSThread* tableViewThread;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSThread* headViewThread;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSThread* tableViewThread;
@end
```

.m:

```
@interface TodoCostApplyViewController ()
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    headViewThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(drawHeadView)
                                               object:nil];
    [headViewThread start];
    tableViewThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(drawTableView)
                                           object:nil];
    [tableViewThread start];   
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [tableViewThread release];
    [headViewThread release];
}
```

Is there a leak of memory about tableViewThread and headViewThread ? 
And if there is a leak, what should I do with this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks fine and i think you missed to post the synthezise calls..

Comment: You have declared properties in the header but not used `@synthesize` or `@dynamic` for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a potential leak. `viewDidLoad` can potentially be called multiple times, in which case you would see memory leaks. Everything you retain in `viewDidLoad` should be released (and set to `nil`) at the latest in `viewDidUnload` (and also in `dealloc`).

Had you used the synthesized setters in `viewDidLoad` (as you should almost always do), the problem would be mitigated because every time `viewDidLoad` was executed, the old thread objects would get released when you assigned the new ones.